# Pandas groupby and apply function on group

Tags: pandas

On a pandas df of the below info

```
STOCK    YR    MONTH  DAY     PRICE
AAA     2022    1     1        10
AAA     2022    1     2        11
AAA     2022    1     3        10
AAA     2022    1     4        15
AAA     2022    1     5        10
BBB     2022    1     1        5
BBB     2022    1     2        10
BBB     2022    2     1        10
BBB     2022    2     2        15
```

I am trying to group by `STOCK` and applying the following function

```
def next_pred(currents):
    model = SimpleExpSmoothing(currents['PRICE'])
    model_fit=model.fit()
    next_price=model_fit.predict()     
    return (int(np.floor(next_price)))
```

I am using the following line of code:

```
future_price =df.groupby(['STOCK']).apply(lambda x: next_pred(x)).reset_index()
```

However, I am getting the below error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed
```

A `print` of the `df['PRICE']` from within the function, prints the data properly. Any suggestions on what might be causing the indexing error?
Thanks!
But I am not sure

Comment: Can't reproduce the error with your data sample. But if I add a STOCK with only nan PRICE, then I get this error. Check if any of your stock has only nan? maybe try `df.dropna(subset=['PRICE']).groupby(['STOCK']).apply(lambda x: next_pred(x))` to see if you get the same error

Comment: Actually, it is not about nan, but about a stock with only one row, is it possible in your real data? so try `df[df['STOCK'].duplicated(keep=False)].groupby(['STOCK']).apply(lambda x: next_pred(x))`

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much...Yes there was 2 groups with only one row each that cause this...Can you post it as a solution and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current sample data, no error. To reproduce the error, add this row for example

```
df.loc[9] = ['CCC',2022,1,1,30]
```

then the error is related to groups that have only one row. One way is then to remove these 1-row groups using `duplicated` like:

```
res = (
    df[df['STOCK'].duplicated(keep=False)]
      .groupby(['STOCK']).apply(lambda x: next_pred(x))
      .reset_index()
)
```